# Get YouTube videoID when the thumbnail is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So, I have this basic "Search YouTube" function going on, the problem is... I have 2 get requests trying to get information from 2 different data URLs

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search
```

and

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
```

So far, I've gotten everything to work with displaying the length of each video and the thumbnails, titles, etc.

But the one thing I seem to be having trouble doing is alerting the videoID of the video that is clicked. It just comes up with "undefined". I have scattered my code for hours on end to find what could be wrong. Any help?

```
function search() {
    $('#results').html('');

    q = $('#search-input').val();

    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
            part: 'snippet, id',
            q: q,
            maxResults: 50,
            type: 'video',
            key: rfm
        },
        function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                $.get(
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos", {
                        part: 'snippet, contentDetails',
                        key: rfm,
                        id: data.items[i].id.videoId
                    },
                    function(video) {
                        if (video.items.length > 0) {
                            var output = getResults(video.items[0]);

                            $("#results").append(output);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
}
```

**Full Code:**
 http://codepen.io/mistkaes/pen/6b6a347c7d24edee15b3491420db4ecd?editors=001

Comment: One of your problem is you have multiple ids with the same name. You can't. You should use class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, you have an error at ln79

```
function getResults(item) {
    console.log(item);  //This is how you should test
    var videoID = item.id.videoId;
    var title = item.snippet.title;
...
```

[image]

As you can see, there is no `item.id.videoId`, you should change that to simply `item.id`.

Result of change:

[image]